# Create protected api for internal use only

Tags: php, json, api

I have created simple web service for my website that generates some json based on request, using php, but I want it to be protected so that only I can use it. I mean it should be available for my website only. No one without my permission should be able to use that json on their website.

What is the best method for that in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using HTTP_REFERRER header field, but it's easily spoofed and therefore insecure.

How about using PHP sessions?

Set some variable in session in your main page script, then check for its existence when processing API requests; if the variable in session is not set, don't serve the content.

Answer (score 0):

Give [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) a try, it is widely used for this propose.

Comment: So maybe just implement a Token based authorization. Users should send one token string in the `header` and you verify on your service, if that token is a valid token. An txt with all tokens separated by `\n` (not exposed) opened with [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and an verification of [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) on that `file` should work for you so.

Answer (score 0):

Only allow your server's IP to access the service. Or do you mean you're calling it from the browser?

Then you'd have to pass some kind of token to the service, proving that you're authenticated to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie to validate, this way you are independent from your ip address.